# Queues stopped working after the update

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

- Laravel Version: 5.6.12
- PHP Version: 7.1.15
- Database Driver & Version: (PostgreSQL) 10.3 (Ubuntu 10.3-1.pgdg16.04+1)

[config/queue.php](https://gist.github.com/Batisska/0625e51e2353f93dc5d5a37811302408)

In the .env file:

```
QUEUE_DRIVER=database
```

[App\Mail\MailTest.php](https://gist.github.com/Batisska/ba64251fbcb34dd23403d735c81bf1b4)

```
Route::get('testmail', function () {
return  Mail::to('***@****', 'Джон Смит')
    ->queue(new \App\Mail\MailTest());
```

});

I run the queue:

```
php artisan queue:work
```

When I try to send a message, I see an entry in the jobs table.

The failed_jobs table is empty.

After sending in the console there are no entries about the queued letters.

Also in the log file there is no information.

Queues stopped working after upgrading to 5.6 or perhaps due to a change in mysql to postgresql.

Without a queue, the mail is sent.

Tell me how can I fix this?

Comment: Tell me how can I start debugging? Errors in the logs do not appear. Even thoughts do not have anything to begin with.

Comment: I am exactly experiencing the same issues as your, I have also tried Queue::put(Mail::to('some_email')->send(new SomeMailer())); suggested in https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/3734 , BTW I am using my own SMTP server & database driver and it's sending email fine using send but had issue with queue.